# I cannot do a curl in webstorm

Tags: javascript, curl

Hi everyone so I recently did this command :

```
curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"password\": \"123\", \"email\": \"test@email.com\"}' http://localhost:3000/auth/create-token
```

I tried without the back slashes but It doesn't work either.

the error message : `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "123", curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "email" curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 17`

Comment: Are all the double quotes supposed to be escaped? `\"Content-Type: application/json\"` are two separate shell arguments without proper quoting. E.g. `'{\"password\": \"123\", \"email\": \"test@email.com\"}'` is properly quoted, so it counts as one argument.

Comment: Even if I do  ``curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"password\": \"123\", \"email\": \"toto@email.com\"}' http://localhost:3000/auth/create-token``
I still got the same problem. :/

Comment: You didn’t remove all the backslashes… simply try `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"password": "123", "email": "toto@email.com"}' http://localhost:3000/auth/create-token`. If this doesn’t work, then there’s some context to your question that you’re not revealing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem by using double quote everywhere.
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"password\": \"123\", \"email\": \"toto@email.com\"}" http://localhost:3000/auth/create-token`